# Catching BitmapFactory exceptions

Tags: android, exception, bitmapfactory

I am simply trying to load a bitmap from a file using the BitmapFactory class as shown:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/myImage.jpg");
```

This works fine except in instances where the file does not exist on filesystem and it throws a java.io.FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory). My question is, how do I catch this exception and keep going? I have surrounded the statement in a try block but the catch statement says it will never be reached for any FileNotFoundException. Taking a look at the BitmapFactory class shows that it doesn't throw any exceptions. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to explicitly define the right `Exception`

```
try{
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/myImage.jpg");
}catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException ex){
   //Caught exception
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried that as well, Eclipse still complains that the block will never be reached.

Comment: Wow I am retarded, forgot to declare a variable after defining the exception.

Comment: @user1917410 So did I in my answer... glad you found out

Answer (score 0):

This answer was tested with Java 11/Android 11 but might still apply to older or newer versions.

> Unable to decode
>
> stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xyz.myapp/files/myimage.png: open
>
> failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

"How do I catch this exception?"

You can't because it's not a real exception. The `decodeFile` function catches the actual exception, then prints it to console using `Log.e` (code copied from the `BitmapFactory` class):

```
catch (Exception e) {
    /*  do nothing.
        If the exception happened on open, bm will be null.
    */
    Log.e("BitmapFactory", "Unable to decode stream: " + e);
}
```

As the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeFile(java.lang.String)) say:

> Returns
>
> Bitmap the resulting decoded bitmap, or null if it could not be decoded.

The only thing you can do is to check if the returned `Bitmap` is null and act accordingly if it is but there's not exception to be caught here.